# Why two routes I can see in network tab, when I am hitting only "categories" route in Laravel/Inertia app?

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes, vuejs3, inertiajs

Is it redirected? If so, what is redirecting if I am hitting "/" route?

web.php:

```
Route::middleware(["can:can_learn"])
        ->controller(CategoriesController::class)
        ->prefix("categories")
        ->group(function () {
            Route::get("/", "index")->name("categories");
        });
```

In controller there is an Index method, that is hit by "categories" or "/" route.

[image: Network tab having two routes one is with query string, one without it]

Comment: May be you are passing optional parameters (`sorted_field`, `sorted_direction`,...) in frontend

Comment: As you are adding `prefix("categories")` to your route group, and it will make the route inside of it like this `"categories"."/" = "categories"` or `"categories"."/index" = "categories/index"`

Comment: Thanks, JS TECH. Yes, I am passing params from front end. Your second comment: do you think that's the problem? The prefix?

Comment: The prefix is not a problem, it is a feature for reducing piece of code.